# ¿Cómo convierto un byte 0x01 a String 1?

Tags: java

Tengo un byte en java y lo necesito en String.

```
byte myByte = 0x01;
String num = myByte.toString();
```

Algo así o no sé, primero lo tranformo a int y luego a String con String.valueof(int)

Pero como convierto primero un byte a un entero? He leído cómo hacerlo desde arreglo de bytes pero si solo tengo un byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
  byte myByte = 0x01;
  String num = new String(new byte[] {myByte});
```

Es importante tambièn definir un encoding para evitar problemas de codificacion, que puede realizarse de esta forma

```
byte myByte = 0x01;
String num = new String(new byte[]{ myByte }, "US-ASCII"));
```

---

Para obtener la representacion String o usando simplemente `String.valueOf()` , de esta forma:

```
String num = String.valueOf(byte);
```

---

Agrego el enlace de una pregunta similar en el sitio en ingles, donde puedes ver varias opciones para realizar esto:

[Convertir byte a String.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654141/convert-byte-to-string-in-java)

Comment: uff muchas gracias!

Comment: Un placer ayudar, como consejo no uses palabras reservadas como nombres de variables, por ejemplo "byte", define otro tipo de nombre por ejemplo  : byte myByte = 0x01; , saludos!

Answer (score 1):

La clase `String` tiene el método `valueOf()` sobrecargado para poder convertir los tipos primitivos a `String` de un modo muy simple. Aunque no existe uno específico que reciba un parámetro de tipo `byte`, el compilador realiza una promoción a `int` e invoca la versión que recibe un entero.

```
    byte unByte = 0x01;
    String num = String.valueOf(unByte);
```